# Showing statisctics to Admin in dspace

Tags: dspace

I have a dspace 4.2 (jspui) installation.
How can I see the usage statistics different from the Admin statistics. I don't see any links to use for view them

However while on the local server and i visit http://localhost/solr/#/statistics, It shows solr with documents in it.
FYI (cant access the above url remotely via the ip or domain)
What do i need to do to have the statistics display.

Also I have already gone through this [doc](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Managing+Usage+Statistics#ManagingUsageStatistics-DSpaceLogConverter) and the log converter and importer works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSPUI, a view statistics button appears on the bottom of pages for which statistics are available.
If you are not seeing these links or buttons, it's likely that they are only enabled for administrators in your installation. Change the configuration parameter "authorization.admin.usage" in dspace/config/modules/usage-statistics.cfg to false in order to make statistics visible for all repository visitors.

`authorization.admin.usage=false`

The complete Statistics documentation for DSpace 4 can be found here: 
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/DSpace+Statistics

Comment: Thanks, made this change, but still not showing. do I need to restart the tomcat7

Comment: Yes a tomcat restart is needed after updating the configuration.